# Finding outliers with wrong Z values in LIDAR data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, lidar, xyz, outlier

I have more than 2000 XYZ (only ground points) .txt files and I have to do Quality Control (QC).

Let's say I have file, which I converted to multipoint (or even singlepart feature). I have mean Z value for a file, but if most of the points are 20-40 metres, and two, three points per file are 70-80 metres (wrong Z values). How to catch these points and remove? On another hand, it could be that in another file 70-80 metres is common Z value and some points wrong Z value 120 metres. In another file 120 metres is common and correct.

How to find and remove points with wrong Z values in LIDAR data?

Standard deviation? Raster cells?

Comment: The problem with using standard deviation for finding outliers here is that there is an assumption made that the distribution of elevations is normal, which it likely isn't.

Comment: I asked before and here's a method that worked after reclassifying the high vegetation outliers as noise.- Las dataset pull down the first returns but unclick the noise 7/18 boxes then follow the DEM/DSM/CHM guidelines found on the Humboldt CA GIS site.

Answer (score 7):

One alternative is [Fusion](http://forsys.cfr.washington.edu/fusion/fusionlatest.html). It is a free software for LiDAR processing and visualization.

I would do this in two steps:

1. Convert the LiDAR xyz'.txt' files to '.las' with `ASCIIIMPORT` tool.
2. Filter out ground returns* outliers using the '.las' file, with `GroundFilter` tool.

<sub>*from you comment under simplexios's answer I'm assuming the LiDAR data are only ground points.</sub>.

Here is one example showing how to process the data.

1. Install Fusion (place it at top hierarchy, right under directory C:).
2. Open Fusion's Main Screen.
3. Click "Tools", choose "Data conversion", and then: "Import Generic ASCII LIDAR data...".
4. Browse you Ascii ".txt" file. Save it as: ".importparam" extension.
5. Install Notepad++. Save notepad++ ".txt" file as ".bat" (batch file).

Let's suppose now:

- Fusion is installed at the following directory: c:\Fusion;
- both the ASCII ".txt" and ".importparam" files are stored in: c:\LIDAR;
- the name of the files above are: "project.txt" and "project.importparam";
- the output (".las") filename will be "project.las".
- the output file with the point cloud without outliers will be "ground_filtered.las".

This is the syntax of Fusion's ASCIIIMPORT program command:

```
ASCIIImport [switches] ParamFile InputFile [OutputFile]
```

Using examples above, write the following code in Notepad++:

```
c:\Fusion\Asciiimport las/ c:\LIDAR\project.importparam c:\LIDAR\project.txt c:\LIDAR\project.las
```

Save the Notepad++ ".bat" file, before running it. Press F5 to execute it.

Now, use the `GroundFilter` command line. It will apply the algorithm of [Kraus and Pfeifer (1998)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924271698000094) that will remove the ground returns outliers.

The syntax of GroundFilter is:

```
GroundFilter [switches] outputfile cellsize datafile1 datafile2
```

Using the 'project.las' file, type the following command:

```
c:\Fusion\GroundFilter c:\LIDAR\ground_filtered.las 5 c:\LIDAR\project.las
```

<sub>Note that GroundFilter allows using more than one input file (datafile), which is your case.</sub>

Here I used a cell size of 5 (meters or feet). Tweak the cell size value according to the point cloud return density.

There are other algorithms to classify ground returns and also filter out ground outliers.

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101786/how-to-determine-bare-earth-from-unclassified-las-file/108342#108342) is an answer which shows how to use the Multiscale Curvature Classification (MCC) algorithm from Evans and Hudak (2007).

Comment: +1 Great advice.  FUSION is an often overlooked Lidar processing package with incredible functionality.

Answer (score 5):

I have found Martin Isenburg's [LAStools](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/) to be indispensable when working with LiDAR data. It can process LAS as well as ASCII (and a few other formats).

As an example:

```
las2las -clip_z 10 100
```

will filter out any points with Z values below 10 or above 100.

Comment: Common Z value differs per file. It could be that in another file 70-80 metres is common Z value and some points wrong Z value 120 metres. In another file 120 metres is common and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to orginal LAS/LAZ file ? It sounds like you have all lidar point in your XYZ file ,rather than only ground points.

And If you know good range for Z-Value tou can remove bad lines in Excel / OCalc, XYZ is jsut ascii text

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I have only ASCII text (no original .las files) and yes, it's only ground points. But what's the difference? LAS if it's only classified or scan angle below -30 or above 30. I can convert to multipoint/singlepart with ArcGIS or to .las with LAStools or LP360. Even I know the mean Z value for LAS dataset it makes no sense while for example I have a xyz file (or .las) which lowest point is 50, highest 150 (let's say one, o three points with wrong Z, buy we don't know yet), so Median will be 100, and MEAN is 85, but the MODE value is 55; 60; 70; 90; 95.

Comment: Maybe there is any option XYZ files converting into raster by cellsize 10, and finding wrong values?

Comment: Moreover, it's 2000 files! one by one? C'mon.

Comment: for i in (*.xyz) ; do perl_script_that_calculates_some_meaningful_range_to_keep_and_remove_other_points_from_xyz_file.perl $i ; done , now do you have idea howto get good range. You can probably do it eith one liner sed or regexp.