# Reading LiDAR attributes from a .mat file?

Tags: python, convert, lidar, las, matlab

I am working on some LiDAR dataset. I am used to importing the LiDAR data from `.las` files. I generally use `liblas` library in Python to import the same.

Recently, I found the dataset in `.mat` format which is actually a structure in MATLAB. What I am able to see in that file is only a single cell which contains all the x,y,z,intensity fields as attributes.

So, to be clear, my query is how to convert this `.mat` file to `.las` file so that I can directly read the attributes using liblas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to convert your .mat file into a text file (.txt), and then, convert it to .las outside MATLAB.

A file with .mat extension can be read with function `load`. See [Supported File Formats](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html) for MATLAB.

```
M = load(filename.mat)
```

To convert it, try [dlmwrite(filename,M)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html), which "writes numeric data in array M to an ASCII format file, filename, using the default delimiter (,) to separate array elements."

```
dlmwrite(filename.txt,M)
```

Then, use some point cloud processing software to convert from .txt to .las. For example, see:

[Finding outliers with wrong Z values in LIDAR data](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53483/finding-outliers-with-wrong-z-values-in-lidar-data/54517#54517).

Comment: Yeah, actually instead I directly read the `.txt` file, copied the Z attributes and then reshaped it into Numpy array. Would try Fusion if needed. :)

Comment: PDAL has matlab support at 1.6.0, but it doesn’t read free-structured data.